# Color faces of a from_pydata mesh depending on face height

Tags: python, mesh

I have some scientific data that I am importing into blender for rendering. I'm trying to make a [Surface plot](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html) plot with a color code.

Scavenging around I found a python script to produce the mesh. I just cannot figure out how to give every surface a different color depending on its height, or even a material.

Here is the code. Any help would be appreciated:

```
import bpy
import math
import numpy as np

x,y=np.meshgrid(np.arange(-100,100),np.arange(-100,100))
r=np.sqrt(x*x+y*y)
values=np.sin(r/10.)
# clear mesh and object
for item in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if item.type == 'MESH':
        bpy.context.scene.objects.unlink(item)
for item in bpy.data.objects:
    if item.type == 'MESH':
        bpy.data.objects.remove(item)
for item in bpy.data.meshes:
    bpy.data.meshes.remove(item)
for item in bpy.data.materials:
    bpy.data.materials.remove(item)

# mesh arrays
verts = []
faces = []

# mesh variables
numX = np.shape(values)[0]
numY = np.shape(values)[1]
scale=2. #how large you want to make the field in x y
# fill verts array
for i in range (0, numX):
    for j in range(0,numY):
        # nomalize range
        x = 2*(i/numX-1/2)
        y = 2*(j/numY-1/2)


        z = values[i,j]

        vert = (x*scale,y*scale,z)
        verts.append(vert)

# fill faces array
count = 0
for i in range (0, numY *(numX-1)):
    if count < numY-1:
        A = i
        B = i+1
        C = (i+numY)+1
        D = (i+numY)
        face = (A,B,C,D)
        faces.append(face)
        count = count + 1
    else:
        count = 0

# create mesh and object
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("wave")
object = bpy.data.objects.new("wave",mesh)

# set mesh location
object.location = (0,0,0)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(object)

# create mesh from python data
mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],faces)
mesh.update(calc_edges=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. What did you use to render ? In cycles I do not see any change for the colors

Comment: Use a material if you can. I read this too fast and thought you wanted to set a Vertex Color layer.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do it with the following node setup:
[image]